# Drop down and radio button not getting validate

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, if-statement

This is a link to a working form : http://jsbin.com/vuroyaparo/2/

I am trying to validate the form on click of any of the three buttons (radiobutton, 4 estimated daily use button, Save Product)

a) If the user clicks on any of the buttons give an alert that shows all the fields that are empty and keep updating the errors as per input.

As I put in my function returnVal in the code i get Errors in console
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'catDropdown' of null*

It runs my function at the start but does not validate even by 1st drop down. catDropdown is a variable that tags the HTML select element.

For checkbox same issue so I attempted to write 2 options (commented at the end of the js file)

I am missing something. (either big or small) = Ahhh;

Can some one help me please. My first attempt at validation.                 I am looking at JS solution only since I dont know Jquery.

**Thanks**

Comment: Please post the actual code within your OP, rather than a link to a JSBIN.  Thanks.  Read and follow:  ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["MVCE"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'catDropdown' of null* arises from the fact that you call `var energyForm = document.getElementById("energyForm");` yet you have no element in your HTML having ID='energyForm'. You can give the form an ID and reference that or, call `document.getElementsByName("energyForm")[0]`.

Also notice that the line `if(energyForm.catDropdown.selectedIndex = 0){`
would be assigning the value 0 to energyForm.catDropdown.selectedIndex, not comparing its value to 0. This aside, you likely just want this line to be: `if(catDropdown.selectedIndex == 0){`

Further notice that the line `var catDropdown = document.getElementById("dd1");` will also return null since you have no element in your HTML with ID='dd1'. **The select with ID='ddl' and name='dd1' can be obtained by using** `var catDropdown = document.getElementById("ddl");` **or** `var catDropdown = document.getElementById("dd1")[0];`

Comment: thanks. energyform issue taken care but I am getting error on this line if(energyForm.catDropdown.selectedIndex === 0){                        Error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined

Comment: See my edit in the second paragraph. You're referencing property 'catDropdown' of `energyForm`, which does not exist. I think you're looking to check `if(catDropdown.selectedIndex == 0)`

Comment: I was trying to check for this (<option value="select">Select-a-Category</option>)  so if the current value is select then show the alert.

Comment: Yes, then you'll want to do `if(catDropdown.selectedIndex == 0)`. Also, it would then seem that your next `if` statement is trying to check the same thing, but selects don't have a `checked` property so this statement isn't semantically correct.

Comment: sorry I am new to code hence need to spend more time with syntax and properties. I got what you are saying now.

Comment: this is my function and I am going till only my 1st alert                                     function returnVal(){


document.getElementsByTagName("energyForm")[0];
var catDropdown = document.getElementById("dd1")[0];

alert("I got the form"); 
 var missingFields = false;
 var strFields = "";
 
 if(catDropdown.selectedIndex == 0){
     //missingFields = true;
     alert("select drop down please");
     //strFields += "Please select Category \n";
                    
                } else {
                      return true;
                }
                
            }

Comment: All the errors are clear now after correction. thanks

Comment: Can you guide me why my 2nd alert is not getting registered in the returnVal function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77651/discussion-between-jbowman-and-accidental-everything).

Comment: Sorry that was accidental. I am not very familar with this.

Comment: Also I am on a very slow machine. Apologies

Comment: No worries! Click the link to chat if you'd like so we can avoid myriad comments here. You may want to check out [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).